# How to make a code async?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Alright so I have a function that calls the MySQL database, fetches some information and does stuff with it. Then it's supposed to compare it. The function is asynchronous, but the issue is that the part that calls the MySQL database is inside a For loop, and when I try to `await` there, it says "await is only valid in async function".

```
async function savePosition(con) {
    let IDs = [];
    let finished = false;
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM Callers;`, (err, callers) => {

        if (err) throw err;

        if (callers.length < 1) throw 'No callers';

        for (let i = 0; i < callers.length; i++) {
            let maxCalls = -1;
            let maxID = "";
            let maxLast = "";

            for (let j = 0; j < callers.length; j++) {
                const uID = callers[j].id;

                let isWritten = false;
                for (let a = 0; a < IDs.length; a++) {
                    if (uID == IDs[a]) isWritten = true;
                }

                if (isWritten) continue;

                con.query(`SELECT * FROM Callers WHERE id = '${uID}';`, (e, curr) => {
                    if (e) throw e;
                    if (Number(curr[0].calls) > maxCalls) {
                        maxID = curr[0].id;
                        console.log(maxID)
                        maxCalls = curr[0].calls;
                    }
                })
            }

            IDs[i] = maxID;
            console.log("maxid" + maxID);
            con.query(`UPDATE Callers SET position = ${i + 1} WHERE id = '${maxID}';`);
        }
    })
}
```

From the following code, the output is:

```
maxid
some id
```

As I said, if I put `await` in the `con.query()` line, it gives the error "Await is only valid in async function". How can I fix this? I want it to first define maxID and then write it in the console

The full error is:

```
C:\...\Sentry\cmds\setkills.js:33
         await con.query(`SELECT * FROM Callers WHERE id = '${uID}';`, (e, curr) => {
         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at jsFiles.forEach (C:\...\Sentry\bot.js:93:20)
```

In `bot.js` line 93:

```
let properties = require(`./cmds/${file}`);
```

Line 92:

```
jsFiles.forEach((file) => {
```

Edit: Included full function.

Comment: The error: `await is only valid in async function` doesnt happen in that code, so post the code that triggers that error if you want help.

Comment: Youre right, Ive gone through the error and it says the error is in: array.foreach((file) => {
  let properties = require(`./cmds/${file}`);

Comment: It seems odd because this error only occurs when i have `await` in the function I sent. There are no errors otherwise.

Comment: @Lolization is the `await` keyword being used as `await con.query()` or inside the callback for `con.query()`?

Comment: This code is very odd because you're doing a query in a loop but the query is exactly the same every time and and you're looping on `callers` but never referencing either `i` or `callers[i]` so there's really no reason to do the same query over and over again or even have the loop at all.  So either this is only part of your code and you need to show us the REAL code or you can get rid of the `for` loop entirely.  This question can't be answered as it is because there's an insufficient description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You also don't appear to understand how non-blocking, asynchronous I/O works in node.js.  You should do a lot of reading about that.  Your `console.log("maxid" + maxID);` will run BEFORE any of your queries are done.

Comment: I added full code and the complete error. @peteb the `await` is used as `await con.query()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated the code, if you can help now that'd be very appreciated. I am aware I don't know much about asynchronous I/O but I was hoping on understanding how to make a blocking code. I do know that the `console.log` will run first, but I am not sure how to make it wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your latest code that uses promises and `async/await` to allow you to use the more synchronous coding style you were using with your asynchronous queries:

```
const util = require('util');

async function savePosition(con) {
    con.queryPromise = util.promisify(con.query);
    let IDs = [];
    let finished = false;
    let callers = await con.queryPromise(`SELECT * FROM Callers;`);

    if (callers.length < 1) throw new Error('No callers');

    for (let i = 0; i < callers.length; i++) {
        let maxCalls = -1;
        let maxID = "";
        let maxLast = "";

        for (let j = 0; j < callers.length; j++) {
            const uID = callers[j].id;

            let isWritten = false;
            for (let a = 0; a < IDs.length; a++) {
                if (uID == IDs[a]) isWritten = true;
            }

            if (isWritten) continue;

            let curr = await con.queryPromise(`SELECT * FROM Callers WHERE id = '${uID}';`);
            if (Number(curr[0].calls) > maxCalls) {
                maxID = curr[0].id;
                console.log(maxID)
                maxCalls = curr[0].calls;
            }
        }

        IDs[i] = maxID;
        console.log("maxid" + maxID);
        await con.queryPromise(`UPDATE Callers SET position = ${i + 1} WHERE id = '${maxID}';`);
    }
}
```

You would call this like this:

```
savePosition(con).then(() => {
    console.log("savePosition() completed successfully");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error in savePosition(), err);
});
```

Comment: Possible you explain why, when using the `await` keyword inside a loop/`.then`/etc. it produces the "await is only valid in async function" error, and when using it outside it doesn't? I'm now trying to do something else, and it produces the same error. The `await` keyword is inside an `async` function, but because it is inside a `.then` it produces the error. Putting it outside of it works fine.

Comment: @Lolization - To use `await`, it must be directly inside of an `async` function.  Not a parent function somewhere above, but the actual function body that it's in must be declared `async`.  So, inside of the callback for `.forEach()` or `.then()`, that callback itself must be declared `async`.  In addition, it probably won't actually do what you want inside a callback who's caller is not expecting a promise to be returned (like `.forEach()`).  Remember, all `async` functions return a promise that is resolved only when all the `await` statements in the function are done.

Comment: @Lolization - If the parent function is `async`, then `await` does work just fine in `for` loop (but not in `.forEach()`) as it is in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used promise and then for achieving this.

```
var Promise = require('promise');
....
function savePosition(con) {
  let getMaxId = ()=>{
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          let maxID;
          let counter=callers.length-1;
          for (let i = 0; i < callers.length; i++) {

            con.query(`SELECT * FROM Callers WHERE id = '${uID}';`, (e, curr) => {
              if (e)
                throw e;
              if (Number(curr[0].calls) > maxCalls) {
                maxID = 'some id';
                maxCalls = curr[0].calls;
              }
               if(counter===0) resolve(maxID);
               else couonter--;
            })

          }
      })
  }

  getMaxId().then((maxID)=>{
      IDs[i] = maxID;
      console.log("maxid" + maxID);
      con.query(`UPDATE Callers SET position = ${i + 1} WHERE id = '${maxID}';`);
  })
}
```

Comment: How should that solve the problem? `resolve(maxID)` would be called before any of the queries `con.query` are finished. So `maxID` would always be `undefined`.

Comment: I have edited the answer, added a counter to ensure all the call backs have returned. Now, resolved gets called only when all the call backs are executed. Pls check.

Comment: If it worked can you please accept the answer for the stack overflow community.